# Access deep objects in a map using a key like "item1.item1A"

Tags: java, maps, key

I have several maps whose keys are strings and its values Objects (`Map<String, Object>`). Those objects could be other maps, lists or literal values (similar to a JSON representation in memory). Example:

```
myMap = {
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "Foo",
      "surname": "Bar"
    },
    {
      "name": "John",
      "surname": "Doe"
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so I was wondering if there is a Java library that would allow me to do something like this:

```
String secondUserSurname = (String) myMap.get("users[1].surname");
```

Thanks

EDIT: To clarify, I need the expression "users[1].surname" to be a string. I would have this data structure in memory, and the expression in a .properties file. The properties file will tell which object to access within the map. That way I can rapidly change the object to access changing the properies file, without changing the Java code that would require a deployment which is costly.

Comment: You can't access a `Map` item by index, that's not how a `Map` works. Why don't you use a `List` implementation instead?

Comment: Why dont you just use JSON in the first place if it behaves like it?

Comment: @TA myMap is a map that contais an entry whose key is "users". The value of that entry is a List<Object> that contais two maps. Each map has two entries with keys "name" and "surname". So accessing myMap.get("users") should return a List<Object> and myMap.get("users[1]") should return an Object.

Comment: @Lino I could use a JSON, but could I eval it in Java? I need the expression "users[1].surname" to be a string, because that string would be in a properties file and could be edited any time to access different objets within the map.

Comment: FWIW, you might want to check Commons:JXPath

Comment: @GyroGearless that may be what I'm looking for, if you want, submit it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @ordago then why don't you just access it via `myMap.get("users")).get(1).get("surname")`. That's not even much more complicated then the desired example code you provided.

Comment: @TA because if I wanted to access say the first user instead the second I would have to change the code to myMap.get("users")).get(0).get("surname"), that would require recompiling and deploying which is costly in my company, and it would be cheaper to have the expression on a properties file which I can change easily, so I can avoid recompiling and deploying. Sorry I should have specified this in the original post. I have edited it now.

Comment: @ordago Why would you need to recompile? You could just extract the index to a variable

Comment: @TA Because if the structure changes to something like this:
myMap = { "users": [ { "personal-data": { "name" : "John", "surname": "Doe" } ] } I would need to recompile. But having it as a string I would only need to change from "users[0].surname" to "users[0].personal-data.surname" in the properties file. I need a bit of flexibility because the data structure changes often, unfortunately more often than deployments are allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library that allows me to access these objects is **JXPath**, as Gyro Gearless pointed in the comments, credit to him.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jxpath/

Answer (score 1):

If you have content available as `String` or `bytes` then you can use any `json` library to deserialise it into a `POJO` and get the fields. Below is an example with [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs):

```
class UserObject {
    private List<User> users;

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}

class User {
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
}
```

Driver code:

```
String content = "{" + 
        "  \"users\": [" + 
        "    {" + 
        "      \"name\": \"Foo\"," + 
        "      \"surname\": \"Bar\"" + 
        "    }," + 
        "    {" + 
        "      \"name\": \"John\"," + 
        "      \"surname\": \"Doe\"" + 
        "    }" + 
        "  ]" + 
        "}";

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
UserObject userObject = objectMapper.readValue(content, UserObject.class);
System.out.println(userObject.getUsers().get(0).getSurname());
```